# lift does not build with sbt?

Tags: lift, sbt, sbt-idea, xsbt-web-plugin

I am following the steps for `sbt 0.10` on the [Assembla Lift wiki](http://www.assembla.com/wiki/show/liftweb/Using_SBT) and get the following error:

```
[warn] ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn] :: UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES ::
[warn] ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn] :: com.github.mpeltonen#sbt-idea_2.8.1;0.10.0-SNAPSHOT: not found
[warn] :: com.github.siasia#xsbt-web-plugin_2.8.1;0.10.1: not found
[warn] ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[info]
```

probably because both pages:

```
http://siasia.github.com/maven2
```

and

```
http://mpeltonen.github.com/maven/
```

don't exist?

My `build.sbt`:

```
name := "MyWeb"

scalaVersion := "2.9.0"

seq(WebPlugin.webSettings: _*)

resolvers += "Web plugin repo" at "http://siasia.github.com/maven2"
resolvers += "Web plugin repo2" at "http://mpeltonen.github.com/maven/"


libraryDependencies ++= {

  val liftVersion = "2.4-M1"

  Seq(
    "net.liftweb" %% "lift-webkit" % liftVersion % "compile->default",
    "net.liftweb" %% "lift-mapper" % liftVersion % "compile->default",
    "net.liftweb" %% "lift-wizard" % liftVersion % "compile->default"
  )

} 

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "junit" % "junit" % "4.5" % "test->default",
  "org.mortbay.jetty" % "jetty" % "6.1.22" % "jetty",
  "javax.servlet" % "servlet-api" % "2.5" % "provided->default",
  "com.h2database" % "h2" % "1.2.138",
  "ch.qos.logback" % "logback-classic" % "0.9.26" % "compile->default"
)
```

and plugins/build.sbt:

```
resolvers += "Web plugin repo" at "http://siasia.github.com/maven2"

libraryDependencies <+= sbtVersion("com.github.siasia" %% "xsbt-web-plugin" % _)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This link might helpful.

https://github.com/siasia/xsbt-web-plugin

Replace contents of project/plugins/build.sbt like below

```
resolvers ++= Seq(
  "Web plugin repo" at "http://siasia.github.com/maven2",
  Resolver.url("Typesafe repository", new java.net.URL("http://typesafe.artifactoryonline.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/"))(Resolver.defaultIvyPatterns)
)

//Following means libraryDependencies += "com.github.siasia" %% "xsbt-web-plugin" % "0.1.0-<sbt version>""
libraryDependencies <+= sbtVersion(v => "com.github.siasia" %% "xsbt-web-plugin" % ("0.1.0-"+v))
```

and replace `seq(WebPlugin.webSettings: _*)` with `seq(webSettings :_*)` in project root's build.sbt

Comment: This really helped me out. I ran into issues trying to compile the existing tests. I had to change the jetty line to `"org.mortbay.jetty" % "jetty" % "6.1.22" % "jetty,test"` and add `"org.scala-tools.testing" % "specs_2.9.0" % "1.6.8" % "test"` to the dependencies as well

Comment: why is it lowercase "seq" ?